# Where are xxx$UNIX2003 functions defined in osx?

Tags: macos, unix

I have an osx executable that runs succesfully. When I run

```
nm mono | grep UNIX
```

on it, I get these results:

```
     U _accept$UNIX2003
     U _bind$UNIX2003
     U _closedir$UNIX2003
     U _connect$UNIX2003
     U _fwrite$UNIX2003
     U _getpeername$UNIX2003
     U _getsockname$UNIX2003
     U _listen$UNIX2003
     U _mmap$UNIX2003
     U _mprotect$UNIX2003
     U _munmap$UNIX2003
     U _nanosleep$UNIX2003
     U _opendir$UNIX2003
     U _pthread_cond_timedwait$UNIX2003
     U _pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003
     U _pthread_join$UNIX2003
     U _recv$UNIX2003
     U _recvfrom$UNIX2003
     U _recvmsg$UNIX2003
     U _semctl$UNIX2003
     U _send$UNIX2003
     U _sendmsg$UNIX2003
     U _sendto$UNIX2003
     U _setenv$UNIX2003
     U _strftime$UNIX2003
     U _unsetenv$UNIX2003
```

Since the app runs succesfully, apparently the OS is able to succesfully resolve these symbols when it loads the application. I am trying to figure out which system library defines these symbols.

One likely suspect is /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib, however, when running

```
nm /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib | grep UNIX
```

there turn out to be no symbols in there with the $UNIX2003 suffix.

I'd like to figure out where these symbols are defined, in relation to a build problem on a seperate program that does not succesfully run, but fails at runtime because it cannot find _opendir$UNIX2003.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the definite discussion in this apple document, [Symbol Variants Release Notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20210210233827/https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/Darwin/SymbolVariantsRelNotes/index.html).

All these are defined in `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib`. Note that it is a universal `dylib`, i.e. contains both 32 bit and 64 bit versions.  On your box, you'll see something like

```
/usr/lib$ nm -arch i386 libSystem.dylib  | grep fputs
000c22c0 T _fputs
000328bc T _fputs$UNIX2003
/usr/lib$ nm -arch x86_64 libSystem.dylib  | grep fputs
00000000000551cf T _fputs
```

The point is, there's no non-SUS compliant versions of these functions in the 64 bit variant. So there's no `$UNIX2003` variant. I guess your linking problem is due to the supported architecture of your library.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! completely solves the problem I've been working on for days now.